# DB2 Copy one column values to another column

Tags: sql, db2, sql-update

In DB2, I have 2 tables - TableA and TableB.
In Table A, there are 10 rows. In Table B, there are 12 rows.
Table A has a column named IntValueA with Integer type.
Table B has a column named IntValueB with Integer type.

I want TableA's IntValueA to replace any 10 TableB's IntValueB values, such that, TableA and TableB will have 10 common values where IntValueA=IntValueB.

IntValueA can replace ANY of IntValueB. No condition.

Can someone please help me how the DB2 query should look like?

Comment: Updating so many rows is going to be slow.  Are you sure you need to do this?

Comment: Yeah. I need to do this.

Comment: how are tableA and tableB related?  Does KEYA = KEYB?  In other words, for a given row in tableA, how do you know which row from tableB to pull IntValueB?

Comment: There are no common values between the two tables. I want to replace any values of 10 keys in Table B with 10 keys in Table A.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
UPDATE 
(SELECT IntValueB, ROWNUMBER() OVER() RN_ FROM TableB) B
SET IntValueB = 
(
SELECT IntValueA 
FROM (SELECT IntValueA, ROWNUMBER() OVER() RN_ FROM TableA) A
WHERE A.RN_ = B.RN_
)
WHERE RN_ <= 10;
```